# Runtime addeventlistener slowing down the application display in Lua using Corona

Tags: sockets, tcp, lua, coronasdk

From my code below, how can I make the Runtime listener running without interrupting the display part of my app? Currently the display is slowing down when I use the Runtime listener. FYI I am new to Lua/Corona and also new here in stackoverflow.

```
function scene:createScene( event )
        group2 = scrollView.new{ top=topBoundary, bottom=bottomBoundary }

        myImage = display.newImage("imgbg1.png")
        myImage.isVisible =  true
        group2:insert(myImage)

        local yval = 120

        socket,err=socket1.connect("host", port)

        while not err do

            socket:settimeout(1)
            socket:send("runcommand\r\n")

            repeat
              line, err = socket:receive()

              if line then 
                no = no + 1

                -- [[ get only the main properties ]] --
                if no >= 5 then 
                reply = reply .. line
                end
              end
            until err

            t1 = reply
            loadnsave:saveToJson(t1,filename)
            tsw = loadnsave:loadData(filename)

            local i = 0

            for k, v in pairs(tsw) do
                i = i + 1
                print("\n" .. k , v )
                locy = locy + 20
                imgBase[i] = display.newImage("image.png")
                imgBase[i].x = locx
                imgBase[i].y = locy
                group2:insert(imgBase[i])

                sw[i] = swfunc(tsw[k],k,locy,i)

                group2:insert(sw[i])

                locy = locy + 40 + iHeight
            end

            inity = 1
            initw = 1
        end

    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", swlistener)

end

function swlistener(event)
    local reply2 = ""
    repeat
      line2, err2 = socket:receive()

      if line2 then 
        reply2 = reply2 .. line2
      end

    until err2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not much mistaken, this has nothing to do with the Runtime listener. Its the socket connection which is probably slowing the app down..

I am not 100% sure(does it freeze the screen? if so then thats the problem)
If the socket connection is indeed the problem, you can do one of the following..

- Use asynchronous method [network.request](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/request.html) if your requirement is a GET/POST request
- [disable the so-called Nagle's algorithm](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#setoption) for sockets
  `socket:setoption(tcp-nodelay,true)`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried as below @SatheeshJM, but it is not working

```
socket,err=socket1.connect("host", port)
socket:setoption("tcp-nodelay",true)
```

I found a solution for this by setting the timeout with smaller value like 0.01

```
socket:settimeout(0.01)
```

Now the socket and the display works fine

But I think i need to change my swlistener function a bit.